# Webcam appears black in Skype, Acer Aspire V3-571G

Tags: 13.04, skype, webcam, acer, aspire

My webcam functions normally on Flash, Cheese, etc. However in Skype, it appears black.

My laptop is Acer Aspire V3-571G.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I keep figuring out solutions to my own questions, but seeing as other people may face the same issue, what fixed it was typing this into terminal `v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl=exposure_auto_priority=1` everytime i start a skype call.