# How to install Logitech Quickcam Express (ID 046d:0928) on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: logitech

How to install Logitech Quickcam Express (ID 046d:0928) on Ubuntu 16.04  It works with Cheese Webcam Booth but not with Skype.

Comment: If it works with Cheese then it's installed and running as it should. Please edit and describe exactly what happens in Skype.

Comment: Dear CelticWarrior,    when I load Skype and go to Options>Video devises than the video picture is black and under the Select Webcam  section there is no facility to select that what is there: Camera(/dev/video). I was told because the Quickcam Express is NOT INSTALLED. So how do I install  QuickCam in Ubuntu OR how do I make Skype to use it. Many thanks in advance for your help. May I add that I am a bit old (80) and not very good at things. Kindest regrds bela Yorke

Comment: Dear CelticWarrior,  I find it somewhat impolite if not rude not to let me know if you don't know the answer to my question or if you don't want to answer it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webcam appears black in Skype, Acer Aspire V3-571G](http://askubuntu.com/questions/295268/webcam-appears-black-in-skype-acer-aspire-v3-571g)

Comment: Dear Sir,  my PC is a DELL dimension 3100 desk top machine that came without webcam and speaker. I added both when I was using Windows. When I bought this Logitech webcam it came with an installation CD. When recently I run "lsusb" it listed my installed webcam. But it is not shown in Skype and I don't know how to make it work. By the way, when I connect to a friend I can talk to him and receive his wideo but my Skype only sends my registration picture and no video. Can you please help!!